# webpack react development mode

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp-webpack

I am not able to configure `Webpack` with react in development mode.

Here is my package `JSON` :

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^4.0.3"
  }
  ...
```

I am getting this `error` in the browser :

> Uncaught Error: Minified React error #37; visit http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=37 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment

When I set web pack to mode development :

```
const DIR_PAGES        = path.join(__dirname, 'pages');
const DIR_TARGET       = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets');
const DIR_TARGET_PAGES = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'assets', 'pages'); 
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",

    /**
     * DEFINE PAGES JS HERE
     */
    entry: {
        'test' : path.join(DIR_PAGES, 'test', 'test.js'),
    },


    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },

    /**
     * HOW TO TRANSCODE JAVASCRIPT
     */
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    },


    /**
     * OUTPUT LOCATION
     */
    output: {
        path: DIR_TARGET_PAGES,
        filename: '[name]/[name].js'
    },

};
```

I am building using `webpack-stream`. here is my build task :

```
const webpack_stream = require('webpack-stream');
const webpack_config = require('./webpack.config.js');

gulp.task('webpack', function() {
    return webpack_stream(webpack_config)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIR_TARGET_JS));
});
```

I am getting this `error` while building web pack using gulp :

```
[13:57:12] 'webpack' errored after 161 ms
[13:57:12] WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'mode'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           mode: ...
         }
       })
     ]


...
```

I don't know what to do can you help me please

Thank you

Comment: It looks like there is something wrong with your webpack configuration. Just showing `{ mode: "development", ...}` we won't be able to help you, sadly.

Comment: @Tholle question was updated

Comment: which webpack version you are using?

Comment: can you show your npm scripts? how are you running the build?

Comment: all is up there, see "webpack": "^4.12.2", And "gulp.task('webpack', function() {", you need to see something specific ?

Comment: what version of webpack webpack-stream is using? Also, you dont need gulp to do what you are trying to do. You can use simple webpack.

Comment: that error message shown is generated by webpack, it is not something that the user has wrote.